# Query with search and subscribers only output

Tags: wp-query, search, wpdb

I can't understand how to make query:

```
$start_from = something;
$results_per_page = 10;

$nameinput= '%' . $wpdb->esc_like($searchinput) . '%';
$emailinput= '%' . $wpdb->esc_like($codeinput) . '%';

$users= $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM hp_users WHERE display_name like %s OR user_email like %s ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 
$start_from,$results_per_page", $nameinput, $emailinput));
```

And I also need these users to be subscribers only. That's I can't do.